# How to pass all values into List Partition

Tags: oracle12c, database-partitioning

as my title, I'm in trouble like this:

I have a non-partitioned table named DISTRICT, now I want to use DBMS_REDEFINITION to change non-partitioned table to partitioned table.

I create a clone table have the same column also datatype with DISTRICT TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE PAR.DISTRICT_CLONE (
ID   NUMBER(10,0),
DISTRICT_NAME    VARCHAR2(1000) ,
STATUS     NUMBER(10,0),
LASTUPDATE DATE,
CREATEBY  VARCHAR2(1000) ,
UPDATEBY    VARCHAR2(1000),
CONSTRAINT PK_DISTRICT PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
PARTITION BY LIST(DISTRICT_NAME)
(
PARTITION REGION_TOTAL VALUES('NY','LA','Washington','Cali','RD'........));
```

In DISTRICT table, I have a lot of unique value at DISTRICT_NAME column and I want to partition all of this.

To do that, I have to pass all values in PARTITION REGION_TOTAL to SPLIT after that. Is there anyway to make it easier?

I'm using Oracle 12C

Thanks!

Comment: I see only one partition REGION_TOTAL that will be holding all the records (as you are listing all the distinct values of Partition Key column DISTRICT_NAME) in one partition. What is the use of partitioning like this? All your record are anyway going to sit in one partition only. Why not use Hash partition instead?

Comment: @ArtBajji Thanks for advice. I know I can use Hash partition instead of List partition. But that's not the answer I expected. I just wanna know whether is any way to replace all values instead of pass each value.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to replace literal values in the VALUES clause of LIST PARTITION in CREATE TABLE syntax except with NULL or DEFAULT.

[image]

Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#i2125928) for detailed syntax.